# Multiple DataBases in Spring-Boot With mariaDB

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-boot, jpa, mariadb

I need to know the simple steps to Access the Repository and Entity Classes from  Multiple Databases.
Example: I have **User** table in **DB1** and **Email** in **DB2** have to access from a single Service Request.

## DB 1

```
spring.datasource.url = jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/dbName1?useSSL=false
spring.datasource.username = user
spring.datasource.password = password
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect = org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto = update
```

## DB 2

```
spring.datasource.url = jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/dbName2?useSSL=false
spring.datasource.username = user
spring.datasource.password = password
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect = org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect
```

## OTHER PROPERTIES

```
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.jdbc.batch_size=20
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.order_inserts=true
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.order_updates=true
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.jdbc.batch_versioned_data=true
spring.servlet.multipart.max-file-size=100MB 
spring.servlet.multipart.max-request-size=100MB
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
@Table(name="tablename", catalog="db2")
```

worked for me

Answer (score 1):

**Solution 1:**

You could create a user that has access to both databases and then use fully qualified table names when querying for the external table.

MySQL supports the dbname.tablename syntax to access tables outside the current database scope.

This requires that the currently connected user has the appropriate rights to read from the requested table in another physical db.

**Solution 2:**

You can configure two datasources as described here:

https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/howto-data-access.html#howto-two-datasources

Comment: i have user who can access both databases

Comment: dbname.tablename creates new table with "_" underScore in 
 a primaryDB *db1*

Comment: Where do you specify dbname.tablename? This must go into the @Table annotation on your entity

Comment: i have specified like this db2.tablename. but creates a new table in db1 like this 
*bd2_tablename*

Comment: It should look like @Table(name="tablename", schema="db2")

Comment: using *@Table(name="tablename", schema="db2")* annotation having same problem @Simon Martinelli

Comment: and what about @Table(name="tablename", catalog="db2")

Answer (score 1):

(Not a direct answer.)

If you will be using text other than plain English, consider these settings:

Hibernate XML:

```
<property name="hibernate.connection.CharSet">utf8mb4</property>
<property name="hibernate.connection.characterEncoding">UTF-8</property>
<property name="hibernate.connection.useUnicode">true</property>
```

Connection url:

```
db.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/db_name?useUnicode=true&character_set_server=utf8mb4
```